# Is there a non-trial-and-error way to determine whether an expression `a Op b ? boolean#1 : boolean#2` can determine order of operations?

Tags: javascript, logic, boolean-logic

**The Scenario:**

Consider the following Javascript expression: `a || b ? 0 : 1`

The output of this statement depends on order of operations. For example, if `a = 1` and `b == 1`, if `||` takes precedence over `?`, then the output is 0, and otherwise 1. Therefore you can run this code to determine the order of operations. In this case, the output is 0, so we know `||` takes precedence over `?`.

Originally, I had `a && b ? 0 : 1` instead, and the expression returns 0 no matter what the precedence of `||` and `?`. I wanted to come up with some expression `a Op b ? boolean#1 : boolean#2` (in this case `Op = '&&'`, `boolean#1 = 0`, and `boolean#2 = 1`) with which I could determine the order of precedence of `||`/`&&` vs `?`. What occurred to me is, "is there any expression `a Op b ? boolean#1 : boolean#2` that gives one output if `||`/`&&` takes precedence over `?`, and a different output if `?` takes precedence? Or does every expression of this form always yield the same value regardless of the order of precedence?". In other words, I wanted to know "Is it possible to determine the order of precedence of `||`/`&&` vs `?` using an expression of the form `a Op b ? boolean#1 : boolean#2`".

**What I Tried:**

By trial and error, I found that `a || b ? 0 : 1` (as mentioned at the beginning of the post) works: if `a = 1` and `b = 1`, the output depends on the order of precedence (output is 0 if `||` takes precedence, and 1 if `?` takes precedence).

**What I Want To Know:**

This is basically a logic question. I used trial and error to determine that "Yes there is an expression of the form `a Op b ? boolean#1 : boolean#2` with which you can determine the order of precedence of `||`/`&&` vs `?`", but I want to know if there is a more logical, conceptual way to answer this question, ie. a way that is not trial and error?

Answer (score 1):

Check if the implicit precedence equals the explicit precedence.

```js
if ((a Op b ? boolean1 : boolean2) === ((a Op b) ? boolean1 : boolean2)) {
    console.log('Op takes precedence');
} else {
    console.log('? takes precedence');
}
```

Comment: thanks for your reply. Using your method, wouldn't you have to supply values for Op, boolean1, and boolean2? So wouldn't this be trial and error for each combination of values?

Answer (score 0):

if your statement looks like this `1 && apple == banana ? "true" : "false"`
it will evaluate everything in && if first and second is `true` (exited with `false`) 
`1 || apple == banana ? "true" : "false"` it will evaluate everything to find `true`. As far as i tested with your example `a || b ? 0 : 1` first statement `||` takes over `?` everytime no matter `a` nor `b` if one of them is true.

Comment: Hi @Sonahit, you're correct that \\ and && takes precedence over ?. My question though was is there a way to know whether there's a way to determine without trial and error whether the expression a Op b ? boolean#1 : boolean#2 can be used to determine the order of operations.